# Javascript not working when echo'd by php

Tags: javascript, php, alert

I have the problem when i echo this:

`echo "Logged in! <script> alert('hello'); </script>";`

The message "Logged in!" appears, but not the alert. How can i fix it so i get the alert? I can't use  `header();` because i already echod things out!

I also tried multiple thing like:

`echo "Test message <script> window.location.href = 'index.php';"`

Same thing again, Test message was echo'd, but the script wasn't run.

I hope someone can help me!

## Edit:

NOTE: All of this code is in a xml file that i get that response of and put that in a div. So the script is in a message that i get with responseXML and output the data in a div.

Question i have in 1 sentence: How can you run a javascript function in a ajax call without jquery?

Comment: Add `ob_start();` at begining of your file and then you can use `header(..);`

Comment: Are you outputting only this? Did you try adding the "basics" html tags around it? (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_html.asp)

Comment: I am outputting this in a big html file with alot of html. I output this in a specific div.

Comment: `ob_start();`  Is not working for me...? code:                     `ob_start():
echo "Logged in!";
header("Location: http://google.com"); `

Comment: Is there any other javascript in the page? Maybe one of them could be causing an error that makes the browser stop executing all other javascript on the page.

Comment: It might be importend that this is a xml file where i do the header() and the script thing. I respond this then to a div.

Comment: There is more javascript in the file. It doesn't give errors!

Comment: do you have alerts disabled?

Comment: I don't have alerts disabled, i also test something else as i already said in my question

Comment: the alert works in http://phpfiddle.org/ so there is obviously some code you are not showing us

Comment: Yes, but as i said: it is in a xml file. That is why it isn't working.

Comment: @Nytrix Let's back up a little bit: my understanding is that you have two pages: one is an HTML page (let's call it Page 1). You visit Page 1, and it has an AJAX call. The AJAX call gets text from a PHP page (let's call it Page 2). Page 2 echos some JavaScript commands, and you want to run those back on Page 1. Is this what you are doing?

Comment: @Chris Yes, and that is not working too ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PHP looks fine, but you might need to change the way that you collect the JavaScript.

Consider this example:
http://jsfiddle.net/0vcewvkc/1/

If you are collecting JavaScript only, you can wrap the response in a jQuery tag (`$()`), and then append it to your document.

```
$("#go").click(function() {  // call the function here
    // your ajax code would go here, but either way you will end up with a string of JavaScript
    var response = '<script>alert("hi");</' + 'script>';

    // use jQuery to append this script to your document's body, like so:
    $(response).appendTo(document.body)        
});
```

---

### Update

To do this without jQuery, the end of your AJAX call would have this code:

```
    var response = 'alert("hi");';  // note that we have removed the <script> tag
    var s = document.createElement("script"); 
    s.innerHTML = response;
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(s);
```

Comment: Do you need to do this with jquery? Because i already done everything with normal javascript....

Comment: @Nytrix I just updated my answer with a non-jQuery option. You can see it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/0vcewvkc/2/ . I did the button click with jQuery, but the inner code should work fine without it.

Comment: I am probaly not getting this right but, when i do it like this:     `echo "Logged in!";
  echo "
  
  <script>

        var response = alert('');
        var s = document.createElement('script');
        s.innerHTML = response;
        document.getElementById('outputLogin').appendChild(s);


  </script>


  ";`

Comment: @Nytrix : "AJAX call" refers to the code that _gets_ the responseXML, not the code within the responseXML itself. My code should be added to the calling page (Page 1, from my comment above). Page 2 should only echo the JavaScript that you want to execute (not any test text, like "Logged in!"). It might be helpful to modify your question to include the code from Page 1.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you call this script through ajax after the page is already loaded. In this case it's not surprising the script isn't running because the browser runs the scripts as it reads them and isn't on standby for another script tag to appear.

If this is the case, you can solve this by adding some event listener or even better, call a desired function in the end of the ajax response.

Comment: How does a desired function work without jquery but with normal javascript? Sorry i am pretty new to ajax

Comment: @LoganMurphy You're right, and your example works perfectly. However it's important to mention that while adding a DOM script element works, adding the script as plain text will not yield the same results.

Comment: The _append_ method creates a DOM element, same as pure js

Answer (score 0):

try the following this should work

```
<?php 
echo 'Logged in ';
?>
<script> alert("hello")</script>;
<?php
  // the rest of your php code
?>
```

Comment: @Nytrix then im sorry i cant help you my knowledge is limited to php mysql js and css but you could try a google search